# How to fetch values from cells inside Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have used grid view in my ASP.NET application.

```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Jurisdiction">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblJurisdiction" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Number">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseNumber" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

in cs file

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
            }
        }
      }
```

Note that the above grid will be populated by data. Now I need to get data from already populated gridview. The above code is not working. Also I need to retrieve from labels, textboxes, checkboxes values inside grid. Please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindControl` method to retrieve the control's data:-

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox;
        Label lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
        ..and so on

        //Finally retrieve the data like your normal control
        string labelText = lblJurisdiction.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the row type is `DataControlRowType.DataRow`.

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
        {       
             if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {               
                for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

To get the TextBox, CheckBox value from the grid use this,

```
string TextBoxvalue = ((TextBox)GridViewID.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBoxName")).Text; 
string CheckBoxvalue = ((CheckBox)GridViewID.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBoxName")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridViewRow.FindControl` method.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
{
    // return you the check-box control from current row
    var chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code .cs file, you are missing to check only for `datarow`. As it will check all 3 places:-

```
1. Header
2. Body
3. Footer
```

Might any one place, any exception can occur.

Please add one more if condtion just `after the for loop`, as below.

> if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
>               {

Hope this post will help's you :).

Answer (score 0):

Use 
cells[i].EditedFormatedValue